Should the [ime] and [input-methods] tags be synonym-ized, and if so which one should we keep?
The ime (30 Qs) and input-methods (10 Qs) tags arose in possible to streamline existing tags?.  I think they're the same thing, but maybe there's some nuance I'm unaware of.
If they're basically the same thing, it would be useful to synonym-ize these.
Question: Should the ime and input-methods tags be synonym-ized, and if so which one should we keep?

"status-planned" => I intend to actually do this [I don't think it's remotely controversial], but I might wait a few days out of caution (as it's not easily reversible).  Please let me know if you think we need to discuss this further.

From wikipedia:

An input method (or input method editor, commonly abbreviated IME) is an operating system component or program that allows any data, such as keyboard strokes or mouse movements, to be received as input.

The above quote is to back up your proposal. As for which one to keep, I vote for keeping input-methods and synonymize ime as I suspect the former is simply clearer to a larger audience.
"IME" might be an acronym not everyone is familiar with, whereas "input method" is more immediate, and autocompletion-friendly. When typing in the tag bar, it's probably more likely to go for the longer version and start with in, which yields input-methods, than the other way around.

Done.  I kept input-methods as per blackgreen's answer, but it can be easily changed if desired.  I added an off-the-top-of-my-head tag wiki (feel free to improve this):

For questions about Chinese input methods, Pinyin, Bopomofo, Cangjie, etc., or just drawing characters by hand.

For the record these were the questions prior to merge.  I'm fairly sure they're tagged based on whether the user first thought of input or IME.
ime

On Linux, how do I output Chinese Characters (not pinyin) using tones in the input
Why cangjie code of 誤 is YRRVK?
Why is my Microsoft Pinyin IME suddenly making traditional characters instead of simplified?
What input method is easier to learn for a someone who can speak Chinese?
Why is the Cangjie code for 海 inconsistent?
How to enter pinyin itself under Windows?
How to enter 女人 with QQ pinyin?
Impact of order of bilingual dictionary entries, dictionary searching, and input method on Chinese learning
How do Chinese themselves enter characters into computer?
How to use RSUNICODE codes?
Chinese IMEs - Wubi, Cangjie
How do you enter a half comma (顿号, dùnhào) with Google Pinyin IME and a French keyboard
Best Android keyboard for inserting pinyin, simplified, and traditional characters
How to type strokes?
Why is 那儿 just one syllable?
Zhuyin IME setting to make tones optional
How to use jyutping as an input method on windows 8.1
MacOS Keyboard with Predictive Completion produces 心情舒暢
How can I get a Cantonese keyboard on an iPhone?
How can I type 吗 in Pinyin keyboard setup?
Zhuyin IME and tone 0/5 syllables
Which IMEs (input method editors) are actually most used in each of PRC, ROC, and Hong Kong?
Is it possible to type traditional characters with a pinyin IME in Windows 7?
How can I type bopomofo on Windows without converting to hanzi?
Typing Chinese radicals?
Dot vs. slash in Chinese computer fonts
How do I type the lü for Character Romanization?
Learning resources for ZhengMa input method?
Input of Simplified Chinese on Windows
Chinese input on Windows based on pinyin and tones

input-methods

Cangjie code for Simplified Character 麦
What is the fastest method to type Chinese using a computer?
How to type the Chinese ellipsis ⋯⋯ using Google Pinyin IME?
How to type zero initial in the common Shuangpin Pinyin keyboard layouts?
Written electronic communication speed in Simplified Chinese vs English
Sogou IME (on Ubuntu): How to output pinyin with tone marks?
Why can't I write the character 台 in my pinyin input method?
Why is the HanYu Pinyin entry method for 亅 "jue3" instead of "jue2"?
How do I get the enumeration comma (、) in Google input tools?
How to write character components on a keyboard?
Learn to type in Pinyin for a Zhuyin user

